# Reading XML and plot multiple Time Series

Tags: xml, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following XML. I would like to extract just the time series data for each day, e.g.,

```
<d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.29</d:BC_1MONTH>
<d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.44</d:BC_3MONTH>
<d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.61</d:BC_6MONTH>
...
```

Then, I would like to store the data in a `pandas` so that I can plot it sumiltaneously so that I can see the changes over each day. Something like this:

```
In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame(the_xml_data, index=ts.index, columns=list('NameOfColums')) # nameofcolumns = d:BC_1MONTH etc...
```

But I can't even get passed the `XML` part. I have tried:

```
import xmltodict
import xml.dom.minidom
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('/home/idf/Documents/python/treasury_curve.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for neighbor in root.iter('entry'):
    print(neighbor)
```

But nothing prints. This is a fraction of the data that I need to store in a `pandas dataframe`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<feed xml:base="http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text">DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData</title>
  <id>http://data.treasury.gov/feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData</id>
  <updated>2018-02-08T21:14:57Z</updated>
  <link rel="self" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData" />
  <entry>
    <id>http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7009)</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2018-02-08T21:14:57Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7009)" />
    <category term="TreasuryDataWarehouseModel.DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">7009</d:Id>
        <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2018-01-02T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
        <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.29</d:BC_1MONTH>
        <d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.44</d:BC_3MONTH>
        <d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.61</d:BC_6MONTH>
        <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.83</d:BC_1YEAR>
        <d:BC_2YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.92</d:BC_2YEAR>
        <d:BC_3YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.01</d:BC_3YEAR>
        <d:BC_5YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.25</d:BC_5YEAR>
        <d:BC_7YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.38</d:BC_7YEAR>
        <d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.46</d:BC_10YEAR>
        <d:BC_20YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.64</d:BC_20YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.81</d:BC_30YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY m:type="Edm.Double">2.81</d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7010)</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2018-02-08T21:14:57Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7010)" />
    <category term="TreasuryDataWarehouseModel.DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">7010</d:Id>
        <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2018-01-03T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
        <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.29</d:BC_1MONTH>
        <d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.41</d:BC_3MONTH>
        <d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.59</d:BC_6MONTH>
        <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.81</d:BC_1YEAR>
        <d:BC_2YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.94</d:BC_2YEAR>
        <d:BC_3YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.02</d:BC_3YEAR>
        <d:BC_5YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.25</d:BC_5YEAR>
        <d:BC_7YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.37</d:BC_7YEAR>
        <d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.44</d:BC_10YEAR>
        <d:BC_20YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.62</d:BC_20YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.78</d:BC_30YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY m:type="Edm.Double">2.78</d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7011)</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2018-02-08T21:14:57Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7011)" />
    <category term="TreasuryDataWarehouseModel.DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">7011</d:Id>
        <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2018-01-04T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
        <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.28</d:BC_1MONTH>
        <d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.41</d:BC_3MONTH>
        <d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.6</d:BC_6MONTH>
        <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.82</d:BC_1YEAR>
        <d:BC_2YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.96</d:BC_2YEAR>
        <d:BC_3YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.05</d:BC_3YEAR>
        <d:BC_5YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.27</d:BC_5YEAR>
        <d:BC_7YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.38</d:BC_7YEAR>
        <d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.46</d:BC_10YEAR>
        <d:BC_20YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.62</d:BC_20YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.79</d:BC_30YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY m:type="Edm.Double">2.79</d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7012)</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2018-02-08T21:14:57Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7012)" />
    <category term="TreasuryDataWarehouseModel.DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">7012</d:Id>
        <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2018-01-05T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
        <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.27</d:BC_1MONTH>
        <d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.39</d:BC_3MONTH>
        <d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.58</d:BC_6MONTH>
        <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.8</d:BC_1YEAR>
        <d:BC_2YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.96</d:BC_2YEAR>
        <d:BC_3YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.06</d:BC_3YEAR>
        <d:BC_5YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.29</d:BC_5YEAR>
        <d:BC_7YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.4</d:BC_7YEAR>
        <d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.47</d:BC_10YEAR>
        <d:BC_20YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.64</d:BC_20YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.81</d:BC_30YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY m:type="Edm.Double">2.81</d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7013)</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2018-02-08T21:14:57Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7013)" />
    <category term="TreasuryDataWarehouseModel.DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">7013</d:Id>
        <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2018-01-08T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
        <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.3</d:BC_1MONTH>
        <d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.45</d:BC_3MONTH>
        <d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.6</d:BC_6MONTH>
        <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.79</d:BC_1YEAR>
        <d:BC_2YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.96</d:BC_2YEAR>
        <d:BC_3YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.07</d:BC_3YEAR>
        <d:BC_5YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.29</d:BC_5YEAR>
        <d:BC_7YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.41</d:BC_7YEAR>
        <d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.49</d:BC_10YEAR>
        <d:BC_20YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.65</d:BC_20YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.81</d:BC_30YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY m:type="Edm.Double">2.81</d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7014)</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2018-02-08T21:14:57Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7014)" />
    <category term="TreasuryDataWarehouseModel.DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">7014</d:Id>
        <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2018-01-09T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
        <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.27</d:BC_1MONTH>
        <d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.44</d:BC_3MONTH>
        <d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.6</d:BC_6MONTH>
        <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.78</d:BC_1YEAR>
        <d:BC_2YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.98</d:BC_2YEAR>
        <d:BC_3YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.09</d:BC_3YEAR>
        <d:BC_5YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.33</d:BC_5YEAR>
        <d:BC_7YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.46</d:BC_7YEAR>
        <d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.55</d:BC_10YEAR>
        <d:BC_20YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.72</d:BC_20YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.88</d:BC_30YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY m:type="Edm.Double">2.88</d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7015)</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2018-02-08T21:14:57Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7015)" />
    <category term="TreasuryDataWarehouseModel.DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">7015</d:Id>
        <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2018-01-10T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
        <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.31</d:BC_1MONTH>
        <d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.42</d:BC_3MONTH>
        <d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.59</d:BC_6MONTH>
        <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.78</d:BC_1YEAR>
        <d:BC_2YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.98</d:BC_2YEAR>
        <d:BC_3YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.08</d:BC_3YEAR>
        <d:BC_5YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.32</d:BC_5YEAR>
        <d:BC_7YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.47</d:BC_7YEAR>
        <d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.55</d:BC_10YEAR>
        <d:BC_20YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.73</d:BC_20YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.88</d:BC_30YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY m:type="Edm.Double">2.88</d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7016)</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2018-02-08T21:14:57Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7016)" />
    <category term="TreasuryDataWarehouseModel.DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">7016</d:Id>
        <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2018-01-11T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
        <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.32</d:BC_1MONTH>
        <d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.43</d:BC_3MONTH>
        <d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.58</d:BC_6MONTH>
        <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.77</d:BC_1YEAR>
        <d:BC_2YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.98</d:BC_2YEAR>
        <d:BC_3YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.09</d:BC_3YEAR>
        <d:BC_5YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.32</d:BC_5YEAR>
        <d:BC_7YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.46</d:BC_7YEAR>
        <d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.54</d:BC_10YEAR>
        <d:BC_20YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.72</d:BC_20YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.91</d:BC_30YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY m:type="Edm.Double">2.91</d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7017)</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2018-02-08T21:14:57Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7017)" />
    <category term="TreasuryDataWarehouseModel.DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">7017</d:Id>
        <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2018-01-12T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
        <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.31</d:BC_1MONTH>
        <d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.43</d:BC_3MONTH>
        <d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.59</d:BC_6MONTH>
        <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.78</d:BC_1YEAR>
        <d:BC_2YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.99</d:BC_2YEAR>
        <d:BC_3YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.12</d:BC_3YEAR>
        <d:BC_5YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.35</d:BC_5YEAR>
        <d:BC_7YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.48</d:BC_7YEAR>
        <d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.55</d:BC_10YEAR>
        <d:BC_20YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.71</d:BC_20YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.85</d:BC_30YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY m:type="Edm.Double">2.85</d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7018)</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2018-02-08T21:14:57Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7018)" />
    <category term="TreasuryDataWarehouseModel.DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">7018</d:Id>
        <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2018-01-16T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
        <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.33</d:BC_1MONTH>
        <d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.45</d:BC_3MONTH>
        <d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.63</d:BC_6MONTH>
        <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.79</d:BC_1YEAR>
        <d:BC_2YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.03</d:BC_2YEAR>
        <d:BC_3YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.12</d:BC_3YEAR>
        <d:BC_5YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.36</d:BC_5YEAR>
        <d:BC_7YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.48</d:BC_7YEAR>
        <d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.54</d:BC_10YEAR>
        <d:BC_20YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.69</d:BC_20YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.83</d:BC_30YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY m:type="Edm.Double">2.83</d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7019)</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2018-02-08T21:14:57Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7019)" />
    <category term="TreasuryDataWarehouseModel.DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">7019</d:Id>
        <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2018-01-17T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
        <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.31</d:BC_1MONTH>
        <d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.44</d:BC_3MONTH>
        <d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.63</d:BC_6MONTH>
        <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.79</d:BC_1YEAR>
        <d:BC_2YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.05</d:BC_2YEAR>
        <d:BC_3YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.15</d:BC_3YEAR>
        <d:BC_5YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.39</d:BC_5YEAR>
        <d:BC_7YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.51</d:BC_7YEAR>
        <d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.57</d:BC_10YEAR>
        <d:BC_20YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.71</d:BC_20YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.84</d:BC_30YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY m:type="Edm.Double">2.84</d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7020)</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2018-02-08T21:14:57Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7020)" />
    <category term="TreasuryDataWarehouseModel.DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">7020</d:Id>
        <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2018-01-18T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
        <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.29</d:BC_1MONTH>
        <d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.45</d:BC_3MONTH>
        <d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.63</d:BC_6MONTH>
        <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.79</d:BC_1YEAR>
        <d:BC_2YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.05</d:BC_2YEAR>
        <d:BC_3YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.17</d:BC_3YEAR>
        <d:BC_5YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.43</d:BC_5YEAR>
        <d:BC_7YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.55</d:BC_7YEAR>
        <d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.62</d:BC_10YEAR>
        <d:BC_20YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.77</d:BC_20YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.9</d:BC_30YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY m:type="Edm.Double">2.9</d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7021)</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2018-02-08T21:14:57Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7021)" />
    <category term="TreasuryDataWarehouseModel.DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">7021</d:Id>
        <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2018-01-19T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
        <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.28</d:BC_1MONTH>
        <d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.44</d:BC_3MONTH>
        <d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.62</d:BC_6MONTH>
        <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.79</d:BC_1YEAR>
        <d:BC_2YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.06</d:BC_2YEAR>
        <d:BC_3YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.2</d:BC_3YEAR>
        <d:BC_5YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.45</d:BC_5YEAR>
        <d:BC_7YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.57</d:BC_7YEAR>
        <d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.64</d:BC_10YEAR>
        <d:BC_20YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.78</d:BC_20YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.91</d:BC_30YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY m:type="Edm.Double">2.91</d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7022)</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2018-02-08T21:14:57Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7022)" />
    <category term="TreasuryDataWarehouseModel.DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">7022</d:Id>
        <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2018-01-22T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
        <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.27</d:BC_1MONTH>
        <d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.44</d:BC_3MONTH>
        <d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.65</d:BC_6MONTH>
        <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.79</d:BC_1YEAR>
        <d:BC_2YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.08</d:BC_2YEAR>
        <d:BC_3YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.21</d:BC_3YEAR>
        <d:BC_5YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.46</d:BC_5YEAR>
        <d:BC_7YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.59</d:BC_7YEAR>
        <d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.66</d:BC_10YEAR>
        <d:BC_20YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.79</d:BC_20YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.93</d:BC_30YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY m:type="Edm.Double">2.93</d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>


  <entry>
    <id>http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7032)</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2018-02-08T21:14:57Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7032)" />
    <category term="TreasuryDataWarehouseModel.DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">7032</d:Id>
        <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2018-02-05T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
        <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.4</d:BC_1MONTH>
        <d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.51</d:BC_3MONTH>
        <d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.67</d:BC_6MONTH>
        <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.85</d:BC_1YEAR>
        <d:BC_2YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.08</d:BC_2YEAR>
        <d:BC_3YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.25</d:BC_3YEAR>
        <d:BC_5YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.5</d:BC_5YEAR>
        <d:BC_7YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.68</d:BC_7YEAR>
        <d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.77</d:BC_10YEAR>
        <d:BC_20YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.92</d:BC_20YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">3.04</d:BC_30YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY m:type="Edm.Double">3.04</d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7033)</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2018-02-08T21:14:57Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7033)" />
    <category term="TreasuryDataWarehouseModel.DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">7033</d:Id>
        <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2018-02-06T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
        <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.48</d:BC_1MONTH>
        <d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.52</d:BC_3MONTH>
        <d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.69</d:BC_6MONTH>
        <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.87</d:BC_1YEAR>
        <d:BC_2YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.1</d:BC_2YEAR>
        <d:BC_3YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.3</d:BC_3YEAR>
        <d:BC_5YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.52</d:BC_5YEAR>
        <d:BC_7YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.7</d:BC_7YEAR>
        <d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.79</d:BC_10YEAR>
        <d:BC_20YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.94</d:BC_20YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">3.06</d:BC_30YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY m:type="Edm.Double">3.06</d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7034)</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2018-02-08T21:14:57Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7034)" />
    <category term="TreasuryDataWarehouseModel.DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">7034</d:Id>
        <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2018-02-07T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
        <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.36</d:BC_1MONTH>
        <d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.55</d:BC_3MONTH>
        <d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.73</d:BC_6MONTH>
        <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.91</d:BC_1YEAR>
        <d:BC_2YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.15</d:BC_2YEAR>
        <d:BC_3YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.33</d:BC_3YEAR>
        <d:BC_5YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.57</d:BC_5YEAR>
        <d:BC_7YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.75</d:BC_7YEAR>
        <d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.84</d:BC_10YEAR>
        <d:BC_20YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">3.01</d:BC_20YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">3.12</d:BC_30YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY m:type="Edm.Double">3.12</d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7035)</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2018-02-08T21:14:57Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7035)" />
    <category term="TreasuryDataWarehouseModel.DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">7035</d:Id>
        <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2018-02-08T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
        <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.32</d:BC_1MONTH>
        <d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.55</d:BC_3MONTH>
        <d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.73</d:BC_6MONTH>
        <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.91</d:BC_1YEAR>
        <d:BC_2YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.13</d:BC_2YEAR>
        <d:BC_3YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.32</d:BC_3YEAR>
        <d:BC_5YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.57</d:BC_5YEAR>
        <d:BC_7YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.76</d:BC_7YEAR>
        <d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.85</d:BC_10YEAR>
        <d:BC_20YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">3.03</d:BC_20YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">3.14</d:BC_30YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY m:type="Edm.Double">3.14</d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
</feed>
```